# Remove weekends in php strtotime()

Tags: php, html, strtotime

I am fetching data from the API which has some API data for the days of the weeks and getting the data on the HTML table, I am fetching data for each day in one column as Wednesday in one column, Thursday in 1 column, ... till Wednesday of next week.

It's showing the Saturdays and Sundays in between, but I want to remove them. Below is my code:

```
$fromDate = (isset($_POST['fromDate'])) ? $_POST['fromDate'] : date("Y-m-d");
$toDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 week", strtotime($fromDate)));
```

I think something needs to be edited in (+1 week) line, but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - the `N` argument gives you a numeric value for the day of the week. Skip the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will iterate for a total of 8 days (`$fromDate` to the same day in the following week and only retain the weekdays.

```
$fromDate=date("Y-m-d");
for($x=0; $x<8; ++$x){
    $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$fromDate +$x day"));
    echo "<br>Date: $date is a ",date('l',strtotime($date))," represented by number ",date('N',strtotime($date));
    if(date('N',strtotime($date))<6){
        echo " WEEKDAY";
        $result[]=$date;
    }else{
        echo " WEEKEND";
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output when starting from a Tuesday:

```
Date: 2017-03-14 is a Tuesday represented by number 2 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-15 is a Wednesday represented by number 3 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-16 is a Thursday represented by number 4 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-17 is a Friday represented by number 5 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-18 is a Saturday represented by number 6 WEEKEND
Date: 2017-03-19 is a Sunday represented by number 7 WEEKEND
Date: 2017-03-20 is a Monday represented by number 1 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-21 is a Tuesday represented by number 2 WEEKDAY
array (
  0 => '2017-03-14',
  1 => '2017-03-15',
  2 => '2017-03-16',
  3 => '2017-03-17',
  4 => '2017-03-20',
  5 => '2017-03-21',
)
```

Output when starting from a Saturday:

```
Date: 2017-03-11 is a Saturday represented by number 6 WEEKEND
Date: 2017-03-12 is a Sunday represented by number 7 WEEKEND
Date: 2017-03-13 is a Monday represented by number 1 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-14 is a Tuesday represented by number 2 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-15 is a Wednesday represented by number 3 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-16 is a Thursday represented by number 4 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-17 is a Friday represented by number 5 WEEKDAY
Date: 2017-03-18 is a Saturday represented by number 6 WEEKEND
array (
  0 => '2017-03-13',
  1 => '2017-03-14',
  2 => '2017-03-15',
  3 => '2017-03-16',
  4 => '2017-03-17',
)
```

Comment: @MohitMittal I realize this is an old question and you've probably moved on from it either successfully or unsuccessfully, but it represents a potentially helpful question to other readers.  For this reason, I didn't want to leave it unresolved.  If you agree that this answer is sufficient for solving the issue, please award it the green tick.